# Getting two specific outputs from the Katago engine

Tags: arguments, command

I am a Go player and a complete novice at programming. I am trying to write a program to use the incredibly powerful (and publicly available) Katago engine to analyze openings on a 9 x 9 board.

I have made a fair amount of progress on my own simply through a process of trial and error, combined with lots of help from ChatGPT. However, I have hit a stumbling block that is either beyond ChatGPT’s capabilities or beyond my capability to ask it the right question, so I thought I’d turn to a forum of real human beings.

Here is a screenshot of Katago running on the KaTrain GUI. What I’m most interested in is the winrate circled on the right side of the screen:

[Screenshot of Katago running on KaTrain GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZW3V.jpg)

You will notice that Katago has also calculated a winrate for each of 21 possible next moves for White. The winrate circled on the right, however, is simply Katago‘s best estimate of White's overall chances of winning given the current board situation.

Clearly, the KaTrain GUI is giving the Katago engine a specific command to make it output that board position winrate. Separately, it is also giving the Katago engine a specific command to make it output its recommendation for White’s best next move. (In this case that move is E3, as can be seen by the light blue circle at that intersection on the screenshot).

For the life of me, though, I can’t figure out what commands and arguments to use to get Katago to yield those two outputs.

Again, the two outputs I want are:

(1) the overall board position winrate
(2) Katago’s suggestion for the next best move

Please note that the overall White winrate of 63.9% (circled in red) is much more robust than any of the predicted winrates of possible next moves, because it’s based on all 100,000 playouts that I had the engine perform. The 64.4% predicted White winrate for the E3 move is based on just 38,400 playouts, so it’s much less robust.

With regard to the winrate, therefore, I want to make sure I'm getting Katago to output the overall board winrate, not just the winrate for one of the possible next moves.

At ChatGPT’s suggestion I ran the Katago engine in a Windows command prompt, typed in “list_commands,” and got the following response:

protocol_version
name
version
known_command
list_commands
quit
boardsize
rectangular_boardsize
clear_board
set_position
komi
get_komi
play
undo
kata-get-rules
kata-set-rule
kata-set-rules
kata-get-param
kata-set-param
kata-list-params
kgs-rules
genmove
genmove_debug
search_debug
clear_cache
showboard
fixed_handicap
place_free_handicap
set_free_handicap
time_settings
kgs-time_settings
time_left
kata-list_time_settings
kata-time_settings
final_score
final_status_list
loadsgf
printsgf
lz-genmove_analyze
kata-genmove_analyze
lz-analyze
kata-analyze
kata-raw-nn
cputime
gomill-cpu_time
kata-benchmark
kata-debug-print-tc
debug_moves
stop

The most likely candidates, to my eye, are the “kata_analyze” and “kata-genmove_analyze” commands, but I can’t for the life of me figure out which command to use, and what arguments to use after the command, to get the two outputs I want.

Answer (score 1):

not sure this will help:
https://github.com/lightvector/KataGo/blob/master/docs/Analysis_Engine.md

analyses query format:
{"id":"foo","moves":[["W","P5"],["B","P6"]],"rules":"tromp-taylor","boardXSize":9,"boardYSize":9}

the command must be single line.